# Swift - New Update gives optional issues

Tags: ios, swift, date, option-type, swift3

I just updated to Xcode 8 and Swift 3 on my iOS project. It now gives me problems in my app. Instead of giving me the right date and time elements, my label is displaying `"Optional(2016)/Optional(09)/Optional(15)"` instead of `"2016/09/15"`. I haven't changed any code since the update and it was correct before. This is what I'm using:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.month, .year, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
var day = components.day
var day1 = components.day
var year = components.year
var month = components.month
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
let seconds = components.second


let timeString = "\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)"
var dateString = "\(year)/\(month)/\(day)"
```

Anybody know new optional syntax?

Comment: Anybody know how to give me the zeros before months 1-9 and days 1-9?

Comment: If you use `DateFormatter` with a `dateFormat` of `yyyy-MM-dd` or `HH:mm:ss`, it will be formatted with leading zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unwrap the variables with `!` when you´re creating your `timeString` and `dateString`:

```
let timeString = "\(hour!):\(minutes!):\(seconds!)"
var dateString = "\(year!)/\(month!)/\(day!)"

print(timeString)
print(dateString)
```

Will print out:

```
6:0:25
2016/9/16
```

Answer (score 3):

All properties of `DateComponents` have been turned into optionals for example

```
var day: Int? { get set }
```

But you can safely unwrap all properties which are specified in the `components` variable.

```
var day = components.day!
```

Comment: Can you always safely unwrap these? Makes you wonder why they became optional.

Comment: @PatrickGoley - They're optional because they might not have any value (depending upon what the first parameter to `dateComponents` was). Any time a value might not have a value, you really should make it optional, and it's presumably why Apple updated `DateComponents` accordingly. It would be a poor design to have them not be optional.

Comment: @PatrickGoley You can (always) safely unwrap all components specified in the function `components(from: date:)`

Comment: @vadian Do you have a reference for that?
I'm thinking that if they were meant to be non-optional values, Apple would have provided a non-optional data type.
So, I don't think it's safe to force-unwrap these values.

Comment: @Womble The goal of the optional date components is to have one single [init method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponents/1948879-init) with default values for all combinations of date components. But there is a confirmation:  The return value of [`component(_:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293299-component) in Calendar is non-optional. `Calendar.Component` is actually the *unit* of `DateComponents`

Answer (score 3):

If you want it formatted with leading zeros, it's probably easiest to use a `DateFormatter`:

```
let date = Date()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let timeString = timeFormatter.string(from: date)
```

---

If you really want to build these strings yourself, use `String(format:)`:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .year, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
let day = components.day
let year = components.year
let month = components.month
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
let seconds = components.second

let timeString = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour!, minutes!, seconds!)
let dateString = String(format: "%04d/%02d/%02d", year!, month!, day!)
```